# I want to code it so that when I open chat in roblox and press something that has the letter "r" in the word, i don't reset

Tags: lua, roblox

can someone help me with that? I already got the code for resetting but when i open chat and say rrrrrrr, i keep dying.

here it is:

```
    local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer  



   local character = player.Character  
   local enabled = true  
   local userinputservice = game:GetService("UserInputService")
   userinputservice.InputBegan:connect(function(input)  
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and enabled then   
            character.Head:Remove()  
            enabled = false  
            wait(6)  
            enabled = true  
        end  
    end)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site. Sorry you're getting downvotes, but there's a specific way to ask a question. Take a minute and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure you tag the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

[`UserInputService#inputBegan`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/UserInputService/InputBegan) gives you `gameProcessedEvent` as the second parameter of the function.

It indicates whether the game engine internally observed this input and acted on it. Generally, this refers to UI processing, so if a button was touched or clicked from this input, `gameProcessedEvent` would be true. This applies to TextBoxes, such as the chat.

All you need to check if if `gameProcessedEvent` is true.

---

```lua
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService");
local PlayersService = game:GetService("Players");

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if gameProcessedEvent then return false end
    if (input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R) then
        PlayersService.LocalPlayer.Character.Head:Destroy()
    end
end)
```